# Ball/Circle collision issue

Tags: java, swing, collision, geometry

I'm trying to get the balls to bounce, or reverse direction when they collide. i have it check for the collision within the move method. it checks if there is a collision between two balls and if its true it'll reverse the speeds. 
The problem is that, once in a while the balls just pass through each other, the smaller balls mostly. balls will either bounce to early, bounce late, get stuck together vibrating,or pass through each other.

```
public class Balls{

public static void main(String[] args){
    new Balls();
}


public Balls(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Balls");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(1000,1000);
    frame.add(new ballHolder());
}
public class ballHolder extends JPanel{
    ;
    public  List<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<>();
    public ballHolder(){
//add balls(x,y,speedX,speedY,radius,color,parent)

        balls.add(new Ball(670,180,2,9,20,Color.RED,this));
        balls.add(new Ball(570,380,-8,-9,20,Color.ORANGE,this));
        balls.add(new Ball(170,780,2,2,50,Color.PINK,this));
        balls.add(new Ball(470,680,5,3,50,Color.GREEN,this));
        balls.add(new Ball(270,280,9,7,50,Color.CYAN,this));

        System.out.println("Number of Balls: "+ balls.size());
        Timer timer = new Timer(20, new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for(Ball ball : balls){
                    ball.move();
                }
                repaint();  
            }});
        timer.start();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        for(Ball ball : balls){
            ball.paint(g2); 
        }
    }
    //gets list of balls
    public  List<Ball> getBalls(){
        return balls;
    }

}

public class Ball{
    int x;
    int y;
    public int speedX;
    public int speedY;
    int radius;
    int height;
    int width;
    Color color;
    ballHolder parent;
    public Ball(int x,int y,int speedX,int speedY,int radius,Color color,ballHolder parent){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.speedX = speedX;
        this.speedY = speedY;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.color = color;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.height = radius * 2;
        this.width = radius * 2;    
    }
    //moves ball
    public void move(){
        x += speedX;
        y += speedY;
        if(x + width > parent.getWidth()){
             x = parent.getWidth() - width;
            speedX = -speedX;
        }else if (0 > x){ 
            x = 0;
            speedX = -speedX;
        }
        if(y + height > parent.getHeight()){
            y = parent.getHeight() - height;
            speedY = -speedY;
        }else if (0 > y){ 
            y = 0;
            speedY = -speedY;
        }
        //check for ball collision
        for(int i=0;i < parent.getBalls().size();i++){
            for(int j=0;j < parent.getBalls().size();j++){
                if(i != j){
                    if(ballCollision(parent.getBalls().get(i), parent.getBalls().get(j))){
                        System.out.println("Collision");
                        parent.getBalls().get(i).speedX *= -1;
                        parent.getBalls().get(i).speedY *= -1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    //checks for collision
    public boolean ballCollision(Ball a, Ball b){
        if((b.x-a.x)*(b.x-a.x) + (a.y-b.y)*(a.y-b.y) <= (a.radius+b.radius)*(a.radius+b.radius)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }                   
    private void paint(Graphics g2){
        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.fillOval(x, y, width, height);

    }
}
}
```

**Updated Version**: with suggestion from J W and ZnW. and added more balls so you can see the problem clearer

```
public class Balls2{

public static void main(String[] args){
    new Balls2();
}


public Balls2(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Balls");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(1000,1000);
    frame.add(new ballHolder());
}
public class ballHolder extends JPanel{
    ;
    public  List<Ball> balls = new ArrayList<>();
    public ballHolder(){
//add balls(x,y,speedX,speedY,radius,color,parent)
        balls.add(new Ball(350,350,0,0,150,Color.PINK,this));

        balls.add(new Ball(500,0,0,10,20,Color.RED,this));
        balls.add(new Ball(0,500,10,0,20,Color.CYAN,this));
        balls.add(new Ball(500,1000,0,-10,20,Color.ORANGE,this));
        balls.add(new Ball(1000,500,-10,0,20,Color.GREEN,this));

        System.out.println("Number of Balls: "+ balls.size());

        Timer timer = new Timer(20, new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for(Ball ball : balls){
                    ball.move();
                    repaint();
                    ball.checkCollision();
                }       

            }});
        timer.start();
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        for(Ball ball : balls){
            ball.paint(g2); 
        }
    }
    //gets list of balls
    public  List<Ball> getBalls(){
        return balls;
    }

}

public class Ball{
    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int speedX;
    private int speedY;
    private int radius;
    private int height;
    private int width;
    private Color color;
    private ballHolder parent;
    public Ball(int x,int y,int speedX,int speedY,int radius,Color color,ballHolder parent){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.speedX = speedX;
        this.speedY = speedY;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.color = color;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.height = radius * 2;
        this.width = radius * 2;    
    }
    //moves ball
    public void move(){

        if(x + width > parent.getWidth()){
             x = parent.getWidth() - width;
            speedX = -speedX;
        }else if (0 > x){ 
            x = 0;
            speedX = -speedX;
        }
        if(y + height > parent.getHeight()){
            y = parent.getHeight() - height;
            speedY = -speedY;
        }else if (0 > y){ 
            y = 0;
            speedY = -speedY;
        }


        x += speedX;
        y += speedY;

    }
    public void checkCollision(){
        for(int j=0;j < parent.getBalls().size();j++){
            if(parent.getBalls().get(j) != this){
                if(ballCollision(parent.getBalls().get(j), this)){
                    System.out.println("Collision");
                    speedX *= -1;
                    speedY *= -1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public boolean ballCollision(Ball a, Ball b){
        if((b.x-a.x)*(b.x-a.x) + (a.y-b.y)*(a.y-b.y) <= (a.radius+b.radius)*(a.radius+b.radius)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }                   
    private void paint(Graphics g2){
        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.fillOval(x, y, width, height);

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ball move and ball collision should not be done in the same function for each ball.  Say you have ball A and B that are about to collide.  Ball A moves and then checks for collision, finds one and reverses direction.  Then ball B moves, and when it does, it could move out of the collision zone before it detects it.  Then it checks for collision and doesn't find one, and keeps going in the same direction.

All balls should be moved, and then you should check for any collisions (or vice versa - they are equivalent).

So I would remove the ball collision check from the `move()` function and create a new function (building on ZnW's suggested improvement):

```
public void checkCollision(){
    for(int j=0;j < parent.getBalls().size();j++){
        if(parent.getBalls().get(j) != this){
            if(ballCollision(parent.getBalls().get(j), this)){
                System.out.println("Collision");
                speedX *= -1;
                speedY *= -1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then in the `actionPerformed` function, add a loop to check the collisions:

```
for(Ball ball : balls){
    ball.checkCollision();
}
```

Comment: tried that didn't work, it can only change the speedX and speedY in the move() method for some reason

Comment: the balls will either bounce to early, bounce late, get stuck together vibrating,or pass through each other

Comment: @JoleMola Make sure the new function is inside the ball class so that it can access speedX and speedY.

Comment: it can access the speedX/Y now, but its still buggy, it will sometimes bounce early/late, get stuck or go through each other. might be that the collision check is to slow, the more balls i add the worse it gets

Comment: @JoleMola Early and late collisions are probably due to the fact collisions are not checked for every pixel of movement.  Two balls coming together may have moved a combined 15 pixels in one iteration before the collision is checked.  As for getting stuck or going through each other, does this happen mainly when more than 2 balls are colliding together?  The collision algorithm being used does not handle this well.  An option to fix that is to set a flag "bounce" to true on any ball involved in a collision, and after all balls have been checked, reverse direction for any with bounce = true.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify the position AFTER all calculations.
And you have very "resource-costly" collision check, you should compare the balls like this:

```
 for (int j = 0; j < parent.getBalls().size(); j++)
     if (parent.getBalls().get(j) != this)
          if (ballCollision(parent.getBalls().get(j), this)) {
                 System.out.println("Collision");
                 parent.getBalls().get(j).speedX *= -1;
                 parent.getBalls().get(j).speedY *= -1;
                 speedX *= -1;
                 speedY *= -1;
             }
         }
```

Just you are comparing all the balls in each ball. You should compare only current ball and another, but not all the balls between all other balls every time.

Comment: This is a good improvement.  However, updating both balls involved in the collision wouldn't work because both balls would find the collision and update themselves and each other, so they would end up going in the same direction they started with.

Comment: Why? As I mentioned above, you should modify position after all calculations. In result other ball won't detect a collision.

Comment: @author: you also should detect collision in next step (by offsetting ball on it's delta vectors between current frame and next). They will be predicted in that way.

Comment: After all calculations per ball or for all balls? Either way has issues. After all balls: in all collisions ball A will detect collision and reverse ball A and B, then ball B will detect collision and reverse ball A and B again, then both will move. After each ball: if ball B's speed is greater than ball A's, ball B could move to a position overlapping ball A such that on the next iteration, ball A will detect collision and move away, but not far enough to undo the collision, so then ball B will detect collision and reverse directions again. The prediction you mention would fix this. :)